# Is there a R function to show dimension of the data

Tags: r

I need to see the dimension of the data set "df" in R shiny.

```
 library(shiny)

 ui <- fluidPage(
 dim(df)
 )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

 }

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried with this code, But only rows number is coming and column number is missing. Why so?

Comment: Well, `dim(df)` will be a vector. Just combine it into a single string value with `paste(dim(df), collapse=", ")`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample of what "df" is. You can do this by using the dput() function.

Comment: @MrFlick What about `toString(dim(df))`?

Comment: `dim(df)` works for matrices only, for vectors the equivalent is `length()`.

Comment: @jay.sf that’s a very sensible suggestion. I just pointed out paste() because it would give you more options about formatting the result.

Comment: thanks all. Can I reduce the size of the text ?